# Load background image with Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, image, tkinter, pycharm

I tried all the post available on google related to my issue but still cannot solve. I am trying to load 1 image as background to the form tkinter is generating. With below code , I am getting error as :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 89, in 
AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'image1'

Below is the code:

```
   from tkinter import *
    import tkinter as tk
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image


    master = Tk()
    master1= Toplevel()
    master.title("Crop Yield Prediction")
    master.geometry('600x600')
   image2 = Image.open('D:\\Pictures\\god0a.jpg')
   image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
   background_label = tk.Label(master1, image=image1)
   background_label.image1
   background_label.photo=background
   background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

Comment: Just because you use `image=image1` in the constructor, doesn't mean it becomes an attribute of `background_label`. If you want that, you should explicitly make it one. In fact, it wouldn't be possible for `tk.Label.__init__` to use `setattr`, because it doesn't know in advance what name the caller will bind to the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Few changes to code and it worked!!

```
image2 = Image.open('D:\\Pictures\\god0a.jpg')
#image2.show()
image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image2)
background_label = tk.Label(master, image=image1)
background_label.image1=image1
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, height=250, width=350)
```